# Multiple key shortcut on keydown is not working in Typescript

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

I am trying to add a shortcut with multiple keys on keydown in typescript, but for some reason, it never goes through the if block.

```
@HostListener("keydown", ['$event'])
trigger(event: KeyboardEvent) {
  if(event.ctrlKey && event.altKey && event.key.toLowerCase() === "m") {
      alert("i got triggered");
  }
}
```

Could anyone point out what am I doing wrong?

Comment: does the function even execute?

Comment: Yes, the function does gets executed. I have a HostListener on it. When I debugged, I see that the event.key.toLowerCase() is getting populated with Control key. When I changed it to event.keyCode === 77. It works. But keycode is deprecated isnt it?

Comment: @AngelaRoux - [Works for me](https://jsfiddle.net/y8xhc0md/). Please update your question with a [mcve] demonstrating the problem, ideally a **runnable** one using Stack Snippets (the `[<>]` toolbar button; [here's how to do one](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/358992/)). (You can do runnable snippets with Angular -- I've seen them -- but sadly no one's written up a specific guide for it.)

Comment: Aah. Very weird. Its not working for me. I am on a Mac. I tried your fiddle. I don't see anything in the console.

Comment: I tried it on my Windows VM. And your fiddle works, where as on Mac (my primary) doesn't work.

Comment: If you do `console.log(event)` on your Mac, do you get the correct values?

Comment: Thanks for your comment on my now-deleted answer. I can never keep Option and Command straight as I don't use a Mac. I've seen a lot of code that uses `e.altKey || e.metaKey`, so... Good luck!

Comment: Would suggest, you log each keypress events and see what those values are first. Then apply your conditional statement.

Comment: @ConnorsFan I console logged them and I found the problem. [CtrlKey and AltKey return true. ] but `event.key.toLowerCase()` is giving me `µ`. I think Alt key on Mac triggers the greek letters or other unicode letters.

Comment: Can you test `event.code` instead of `event.key`?

Comment: I just tested in Chrome on my PC and I have the same problem as you: `event.key` is `µ`. Moreover, I see that the `alt` and `ctrl` flags are not set in the event.

Comment: @ConnorsFan Interesting. As of now, I just used the `keyCode` to fix the problem even though it's deprecated. But need to think of a alternative and cleaner approach with `event.key`